# Sphinx initial configuration hungs at checking for CFLAGS needed

Tags: server, amazon-ec2

I have never had any problem installing Sphinx on Ubuntu (local and Sphinx 2.0.2). Always
worked out of the box. Today I tried to install Sphinx 2.0.3 on Ubuntu 11.10 on Amazon EC2.

I have started with "./configure --prefix=/home/sphinx" as usual. Have all MySQL libs and
essential package all in place.

It just doesn't go through "**checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads...**". Below is the
output. Tried Sphinx 2.0.2 as well. No luck.

Btw, you can notice under "checking for header files" block that pthread headers exists:

```
.....
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
....
```

What should I check?

```
checking build environment
--------------------------

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no

checking for compiler programs
------------------------------

checking whether to compile debug version... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib

checking for header files
-------------------------

checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking expat.h usability... no
checking expat.h presence... no
checking for expat.h... no
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking sql.h usability... no
checking sql.h presence... no
checking for sql.h... no
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes

checking for types
------------------

checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes

checking for library functions
------------------------------

checking for pid_t... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
checking types of arguments for select... int,fd_set *,struct timeval *
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for library containing setsockopt... none required
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for library containing XML_Parse... no
checking for library containing iconv... none required
checking for library containing inflate... -lz
checking for library containing logf... -lm
checking for dup2... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for logf... yes
checking for pread... yes
checking for backtrace... yes
checking for backtrace_symbols... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for LOCK_EX in sys/file.h... yes
checking for F_SETLKW in fcntl.h... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for dlopen... yes
checking for dlerror... yes

configuring Sphinx
------------------

checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads...
```

Answer (score 1):

I just installed on 11.10 from this ppa no problems: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/sphinxsearch

of course that's no good if you need to build from source.